# gathering tweets from twitter api python

Tags: python, twitter

i am trying to run this script to gather tweets from twitter but it wont run, it keeps saying syntax invalid. I want to gather the tweets adn save them to an amazon instance,but currently it wont run, i have all the twitter keys and access tokens created and inserted into the script bellow also

Python 3.3.4 (v3.3.4:7ff62415e426, Feb 10 2014, 18:13:51) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

```
>>> import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib



access_token_key = "****"
access_token_secret = "******"

consumer_key = "******"
consumer_secret = "******"

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

'''
Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
using the hard-coded credentials above.
'''
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

def fetchsamples():
  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  for line in response:
    print line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':

  fetchsamples()
```

Comment: please post the traceback

Comment: i am just a beginner what do you mean by tracback?

Comment: See Wikipedia article on [**traceback**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Comment: wont show any traceback,,when  run the code by clicking f5 just says inlvaid syntax

Comment: If you're using IDLE, the line with invalid syntax should be highlighted red after you hit f5.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of you code contains syntactic error due to these three greater-than signs:

```
$ cat z.py
>>> import oauth2 as oauth
$ python z.py
  File "z.py", line 1
    >>> import oauth2 as oauth
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```